# css style for button display

Tags: html, css

I want to display the button on right side.Now IT is also displaying in right side.But I want to change the order of the button.

I want to display in the order add,edit and logout.

[image: button display]

```
.lout{
  float: right;  
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.log {
  width:60%;
  height: 10%;
  position:absolute;
  border: 1px solid #f9f2f2;
  border-radius: 10px;

  text-align: center;
  line-height:20px;
  border-width: 0px 0px 1px 1px;
  display:inline-block; 
}
button.logout{
  display:inline;
  float:right;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

```html
 <form method="post" class="lout" >  <button name="add"  class="add" onclick="admin()">Add</button> <button name="edit" class="edit" onclick="edit()">Edit</button><p style="padding-left:5px;" > <button class="logout" name="logout" >Logout</button></form>
```

Comment: Move the `HTML` around....

Comment: Its working fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/0kxfx1pm/

Comment: ya but having problem with my code

Comment: Then post whole code / demo?

Comment: there is a typo in your html

Comment: As you can see from the demo there is no problem. You clearly have not given us **all** relevant code, we cannot help you if you can't recreate the problem with the code given in the question.

Comment: there is a typo, replace this in your html `<form method="post" class="lout" > 
 <button name="add"  class="add" onclick="admin()">Add</button>
 <button name="edit" class="edit" onclick="edit()">Edit</button>
<button class="logout" name="logout" >Logout</button>
 </form>`

Comment: I will provide jsfiddle now

Comment: @ChaosClown Please do not edit questions code like that. Editing the `HTML` like you just tried to do could cause problems as it could be the very problem the OP is having with the code.

Comment: @user3386779 Updated my JSFiddle... Check that out...

Comment: sry i just copied the spaces :-/ i hate stackoverflows textarea, which should be more like jsfiddle or something...

Comment: Is Comment line for my css code is correct?

Comment: @user3386779 So you want it like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/22vcotev/2/). There is no need to float the buttons, just use `inline-block` and move the `HTML` to whatever you want it as. [**Demo of your version**](http://jsfiddle.net/22vcotev/3/)

Comment: ya I want like that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/22vcotev/5/ Move your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these random answer are getting annoying. The way I would do it and most probably the best way is to remove the float from the button's get rid of the random `<p>` in there too.

We can just simple use `display: inline-block;` and then set `.logout` to push the others away a bit more using `margin-left: 10px;`.

```css
.lout {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.add,
.edit,
.logout {
  display: inline-block;
}
.logout {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" class="lout">
  <button name="add" class="add" onclick="admin()">Add</button>
  <button name="edit" class="edit" onclick="edit()">Edit</button>
  <button class="logout" name="logout">Logout</button>
</form>
```

[**Demo with this in your JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/22vcotev/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
<form method="post" class="lout" > 
    <button name="add"  class="add" onclick="admin()">Add</button> 
    <button name="edit" class="edit" onclick="edit()">Edit</button>                            
    <button class="logout" name="logout" >Logout</button>
</form>

.add,.edit{      
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.logout{
    display:block;
    float:right;
    margin-left:5px;
}
```

Working JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DivakarDass/22vcotev/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try This..

```css
.lout{
float: right; 
 
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 10px;
   }

button.logout{
display:inline;
    background:red;
float:right;
margin-left:5px;
    border-radius:4px;
}
button.add{
display:inline;
    background:rgb(66, 226, 66);
float:left;
margin-left:5px;
    border-radius:4px;
}

button.edit{
display:inline;
    background:rgb(255, 213, 0);
float:left;
margin-left:5px;
    border-radius:4px;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" class="lout" > 
    <button class="logout" name="logout" >Logout</button>
    <button name="add"  class="add" onclick="admin()">Add</button>
    <button name="edit" class="edit" onclick="edit()">Edit</button>
    
</form>
```

Here is [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bLy9919m/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Elements reverse their order when you `float: right` them. Two options here:

- Reverse their order in the HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/0omLy88h/1/
- Put them inside a div, and `float: right` that div: https://jsfiddle.net/jjbL91k0/1/

Both make use of the `class="group"` way of auto-clearing floating children, [taken from here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need style for each button. Simply matters is your order of buttons.

```
<form method="post" class="lout" >
<button class="logout" name="logout" >Logout</button>
<button name="edit" class="edit" onclick="edit()">Edit</button>
<button name="add"  class="add" onclick="admin()">Add</button>
</form>
```

And the css is-

```
.lout{
    float: right;  
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
 }
button{
margin-left:10px;  
display:inline;
float:right;
}
```